# How can I count the spaces and symbols in a string in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that can determine whether a word or sentence is an anagram. I've come this far, but I can't figure out how to tell my function to handle special characters such as '!' or '?', or spaces in the string. Right now, the function will read spaces and symbols and return an anagram as False. Here's the code

```
def is_anagram(string_a, string_b):
    string_a.lower()
    string_b.lower()
    if len(string_a) != len(string_b):
        return False
    char_times_a = dict()
    char_times_b = dict()
    for i in range(len(string_a)):
        if string_a[i] not in char_times_a.keys():
            char_times_a[string_a[i]] = 0
        else:
            char_times_a[string_a[i]] += 1
        if string_b[i] not in char_times_b.keys():
            char_times_b[string_b[i]] = 0
        else:
            char_times_b[string_b[i]] += 1
    return char_times_a == char_times_b
```

is_anagram('scar', 'cars')
True

is_anagram('Tom Marvolo Riddle', 'I am Lord Voldemort')
False

that last statement should return as true, because it is an anagram.

Comment: Have a look at the constants defined in the [`string` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html); they can be useful.

Comment: What's the rule that tells you that `'!'` and `'?'` are "special"? Also, why do you think the spaces and "special characters" are the only problem? For example, do you expect `'x'` to be an anagram of `'X'`? Does your code say it is? You need to think about your requirements carefully before you can ask a question about them - though I can assure you, each step you need to take here is something that you can research easily with a search engine. In fact, you can probably put `python anagram finder` into a search engine and get useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your function considers a *whitespace* as part of the set of chars alongside the other letters. This might be what you want, bit then your second example is indeed not an anagram because there is different number of whitespaces.

Specifically, this line returns `False` for your example:

```py
if len(string_a) != len(string_b):
        return False
```

But even if you would remove it, your function counts the number of whitespaces, and also the characters are not lowercased, so it will return `False` either way.

Answer (score 0):

Change the first two lines of the function from:

```
string_a.lower()
string_b.lower()
```

To:

```
string_a = string_a.lower().replace(' ', '')
string_b = string_b.lower().replace(' ', '')
```

You need to assign it back and also replace the spaces, `lower` does not do it in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your functions like :

```
def is_anagram(string_a, string_b):
    return set(string_a.lower()) == set(string_b.lower()) and len(string_a) == len(string_b)
```

or

```
def is_anagram(string_a, string_b):
    return sorted(string_a.lower()) == sorted(string_b.lower())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to remove all instances of special characters and white spaces from a string. The `isalnum` method returns True for alphanumeric characters. The lower method was included to prevent an error if your function is case sensitive.

```
string_a =  ''.join(filter(str.isalnum, string_a)).lower() 
string_b =  ''.join(filter(str.isalnum, string_b)).lower()
```